# Simple mysql trigger statement in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I am trying to create a simple trigger for my library database.

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE msg varchar(100);
  SET msg = CONCAT('Hi ', NEW.name, 'Welcome to the Library Database'); 
END
```

Here is the SQL statement I inserted:

```
INSERT INTO `membership` (`student_id`, `name`, `phone_num`, `email`) VALUES ('1234506', 'Ari Fletcher', '7083595678', 'afletcher@gmail.edu');
```

It's not showing any errors but it's displaying the welcome message when I insert a new row in the table. I would be grateful for any help.

Thank you!

Comment: Trigger cannot send something directly to the output stream. You may signal a custom error message - but this breaks the statement.

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Hi Im trying to create a simple trigger that says hi to the new user.